# Python Invalid syntax def функция

Tags: python

```
x=int(input("Введите x:")
def square():
    return 4*x,x**2
print(square(x))
```

Выделяет букву d в слове def и пишет Invalid syntax

Comment: Скобку не закрыли.

Comment: загляните в учебник)

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка синтаксиса, вы забыли закрыть скобку в первой строке.

```
x = int(input("Введите x:"))
def square(x):
    return 4*x,x**2
print(square(x))
```

Comment: только скобки не хватает?.. и работает?

Comment: Пофиксил, забыл передать переменную в функцию.

Answer (score 0):

В первой строчке не хватает круглой скобки в конце.